# Test assertions inside test doubles?

Tags: testing, mocking, googletest, clean-architecture, spy

Is it a good practice to write a EXPECT(something) inside a test double (e.g. spy or mock) method? To ensure the test double is used in a specific way for testing?
If not, what would be a preferred solution?

Comment: What is "test double"?

Comment: Test double is a replacement of a production object for testing purposes (I like this definition by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to put all `EXPECT` statements inside individual tests to make your code readable.

If you want to enforce certain things on your test stub/spy, it is probably better to use exceptions or static asserts because your test is usually using them as a black box, and it uses them in an unintended way, your code will either not get compiled, or it will throw and give you the full stack trace which also will cause your test to fail (so you can catch the misuse).

For mocks, however, you have full control over the use and you can be very specific about how they are called and used inside each test. For example in Google test, using GMock [matchers](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html), you can say something like:

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(turtle, Forward(Ge(100)));
```

which means expect `Forward` to be called on the mock object `turtle` with a parameter equal or greater than 100. Any other value will cause the test to fail.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfJobi4b_pw) for more examples on GMock matchers.

It is also very common to check general things in a test fixture (e.g. in Setup or TearDown). For example, [this sample](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/samples/sample5_unittest.cc) from google test enforces each test to finish in a certain amount of time, and the `EXPECT` statement is in `teardown` rather than each individual test.

Answer (score 0):

If you would write a true ***Mock*** (as per definition from [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mock%20Object.html)) this is exactly what defines this kind of test double. It is set up with the expectations how it will be called and therefore also includes the assertions. That's also how mocking frameworks produce mock objects under the hood. See also the definition from xUnit Test Patterns:

> How do we implement Behavior Verification for indirect outputs of the SUT?
> How can we verify logic independently when it depends on indirect inputs from other software components?

> Replace an object the system under test (SUT) depends on with a test-specific object that verifies it is being used correctly by the SUT.

Here, *indirect outputs* means that you don't want to verify that the method under test returns some value but that there is something happening inside the method being tested that is behaviour relevant to callers of the method. For instance, that while executing some method the correct behaviour lead to an expected important action. Like sending an email or sending a message somewhere. The mock would be the ***doubled*** dependency that also verifies itself that this really happened, i.e. that the method under test really called the method of the dependency with the expected parameter(s).

A ***spy*** on the other hand shall just record things of interest that happened to the doubled dependency. *Interrogating* the spy about what happened (and sometimes also how often) and then judging if that was correct by asserting on the expected events is the responsibility of the test itself. So a mock is always also a spy with the addition of the assertion (expectation) logic. See also Uncle Bobs blog [The Little Mocker](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html) for a great explanation of the different types of test doubles.

**TL;DR**

Yes, the mock includes the expectations (assertion) itself, the spy just records what happened and lets the test itself asks the spy and asserts on the expected events.

Mocking frameworks also implement mocks like explained above as they all follow the specified xunit framework.

```
mock.Verify(p => p.Send(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

If you look at the above [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq) example (C#), you see that the mock object itself is configured to in the end perform the expected verification. The framework makes sure that the mock's verification methods are executed. A hand-written would be setup and than you would call the verification method on the mock object yourself.